# how to set div width with image size

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have div with id="picBox" that image tag and two div that contains pic title and pic content in it. I want "picBox" width equal with the image tag.
but I can't do it.
what can I do to solve it?
thanks.

The CSS code:

```css
.galleryPicBox {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    height: 420px;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

    .galleryPicBox div {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0 auto;
        color: white;
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;
        text-align: center;
        transition: visibility 1s, opacity 1s linear;
        _webkit_transition: visibility 1s, opacity 1s linear;
    }

    .galleryPicBox:hover div {
        visibility: hidden;
        opacity: 0;
    }

    .galleryPicBox div div {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        line-height: 35px;
        background: rgba(180, 180, 180, 0.5);
    }

    .galleryPicBox div:last-child {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0 !important;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        line-height: 22px;
    }

    .galleryPicBox .imgStyle {
        max-height: 420px;
        max-width: 100%;
        image-orientation: from-image;
    }


the html code:
```

```html
<div id="picBack" runat="server" class="galleryPicBox" style="background:rgb(93, 147, 184);">
    <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" class="imgStyle" />
        <div id="divPicDetail" runat="server">
             <div id="divPicTitle" runat="server">
                                pic Title
             </div>
             <div id="divPicContent" runat="server">
                                picContent
             </div>
         </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `width: auto; display: inline-block;` to `.galleryPicBox`?

Comment: thank you. with this style the problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Remove **padding: 5px 10px;** from your style shown below

```
 .galleryPicBox div:last-child {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0 !important;
        padding: 5px 10px; // Remove this line
        line-height: 22px;
    }
```

```css
.galleryPicBox {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    height: 420px;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

    .galleryPicBox div {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0 auto;
        color: white;
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;
        text-align: center;
        transition: visibility 1s, opacity 1s linear;
        _webkit_transition: visibility 1s, opacity 1s linear;
    }

    .galleryPicBox:hover div {
        visibility: hidden;
        opacity: 0;
    }

    .galleryPicBox div div {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        line-height: 35px;
        background: rgba(180, 180, 180, 0.5);
    }

    .galleryPicBox div:last-child {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0 !important;
        line-height: 22px;
    }

    .galleryPicBox .imgStyle {
        max-height: 420px;
        max-width: 100%;
        image-orientation: from-image;
    }


the html code:
```

```html
<div id="picBack" runat="server" class="galleryPicBox" style="background:rgb(93, 147, 184);">
    <img width='100%' src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" class="imgStyle" />
        <div id="divPicDetail" runat="server">
             <div id="divPicTitle" runat="server">
                                pic Title
             </div>
             <div id="divPicContent" runat="server">
                                picContent
             </div>
         </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery for it like this

```js
var imagWidth = $('.imgStyle').width();
var picBox = $('.galleryPicBox').width(imagWidth);
```

```css
.galleryPicBox {
/*width: 100%; */
position: relative;
height: 420px;
padding: 0;
text-align: center;
background:rgb(93, 147, 184);
}

.galleryPicBox div {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto;
color: white;
visibility: visible;
opacity: 1;
text-align: center;
transition: visibility 1s, opacity 1s linear;
_webkit_transition: visibility 1s, opacity 1s linear;
}

.galleryPicBox:hover div {
visibility: hidden;
opacity: 0;
}

.galleryPicBox div div {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
line-height: 35px;
background: rgba(180, 180, 180, 0.5);
}

.galleryPicBox div:last-child {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0 !important;
padding: 5px 10px;
line-height: 22px;
}

.galleryPicBox .imgStyle {
max-height: 420px;
max-width: 100%;
image-orientation: from-image;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="picBack" runat="server" class="galleryPicBox">
<img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" class="imgStyle" />
<div id="divPicDetail" runat="server">
<div id="divPicTitle" runat="server">pic Title</div>
<div id="divPicContent" runat="server">picContent</div>
</div>
</div>
```